# how to make navigation link indicator expand in active state?

Tags: css, hyperlink, youtube, navigation, expand

[image: An image showing the animation]

How can I make link indicator expand when the state is active? In every YouTube channel we have a navigation bar which has this kind of effect. How can I do this in code?

I have inspected the elements in browser and I noticed that, they are using `translateX(somevalue); scaleX(somevalue)` but my question is how it's keeping track of what amount to grow? and overall how to make this kind of effect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this by listening to a click on the list items.

When an item is clicked, get it's position and move the "indicator" element into the correct position.

Maybe something like this:

```js
// Get elements
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item');
const indicator = document.querySelector('.indicator');
let activeItem = document.querySelector('.list__item--active');

// Add click listeners to each list item
listItems.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', handleItemClick);
});

// Run the updateIndicator function to add indicator at correct posiiton when the page first loads
updateIndicator();

// When an item is clicked, set that item as the active on and update everything
function handleItemClick(event) {
  activeItem = event.currentTarget;
  updateUI();
  updateIndicator();
}

// Update active classes on the list items, according to the currently active item
function updateUI() {
  listItems.forEach((item) => {
    if (item === activeItem) {
      item.classList.add('list__item--active');
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('list__item--active');
    }
  });
}

// Move the indicator to the correct position
function updateIndicator() {
  const rect = activeItem.getBoundingClientRect();
  indicator.style.left = `${rect.left}px`;
  indicator.style.width = `${rect.width}px`;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list__item {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.list__item:not(.list__item--active) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list__item--active {
  color: red;
}

.list__item:not(.list__item--active):hover {
  color: orange;
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item list__item--active">Item one</li>
    <li class="list__item">Item two</li>
    <li class="list__item">Item three</li>
    <li class="list__item">Item four</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="indicator"></span>
</div>
```